# two items with the same attributes in YAML

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

It is possible, to do several items in YAML file with identical attributes, but with out need to actually duplicate them?
For example, I have:

```
item1:  
    it_one:  
        some: {...}  
    it_two:
        somemore: {...}
item2:
    the_same_as_in_item1
```

How can I specify, that item1 and item2 are have the same attributes?
At the end I want to:

```
item1[it_one][some]  
item2[it_one][some]
```

Give me identical result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mechanism in YAML that could help you out is using [anchors and aliases](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2765878). With those you have to watch out though, because when you alias a YAML mapping (loaded as a Python `dict` ), that you will get the same instance of that `dict` attached to `item1` and `item2`.

If that is not what you want there is a specific interpretation of an alias in the form of a [merge key](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html). To use that specify a key `<<`:

```
item1: &repl  
    it_one:  
        some: {...}  
    it_two:
        somemore: {...}
item2:
    <<: *repl
```

this will give you, at least directly under `item2` a new dict with the same keys/values as for `item1` (i.e. keys `it_one`, `it_two`). However again the values for those keys (`some: {}`) will be the same object, due to the way this is loaded and handled internally.

If that kind of object reuse is problematic, you better stick with a non-merge use of the alias:

```
item1: &repl  
    it_one:  
        some: {...}  
    it_two:
        somemore: {...}
item2: *repl
```

and walk over the tree recursively duplicating the key-values in new dicts (and lists).

Please note that if you use the `round_trip_loader` in [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/), you will even share the everything, even when using merge keys. Without that round-tripping would not be possible, so use the `safe_loader` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I wish I could double vote you up!